# Loop unrolling with pixels in C++

Tags: c++, performance, pixel

I have a relatively large loop and want to unroll it to speed up my application a little. The code is:

```
byte* oRow = (byte*)bitmapData1.Scan0 + (y * bitmapData1.Stride);
        for (UINT x = 0; x < 4000; ++x)
        {
            #pragma unroll
            byte grey = (
                (oRow[x + x + x] * 114) + //B
                (oRow[x + x + x + 1] * 587) +  //G
                (oRow[x + x + x + 2] * 299)) / 1000; //R

            fl_x = floor(x + x);
            fl_y = floor(y + y);

            cl_x = fl_x + 1;
            if (cl_x >= 4752)
                cl_x = fl_x;

            cl_y = fl_y + 1;
            if (cl_y >= 3168)
                cl_y = fl_y;

            fractionX = x + x - fl_x;
            fractionY = y + y - fl_y;
            oneMinusX = 1.0 - fractionX;
            oneMinusY = 1.0 - fractionY;

            b1 = oneMinusX * grey + fractionX * grey;
            b2 = oneMinusX * grey + fractionX * grey;
            blue = oneMinusY * (b1)+fractionY * (b2);

            b1 = oneMinusX * grey + fractionX * grey;
            b2 = oneMinusX * grey + fractionX * grey;
            green = oneMinusY * (b1)+fractionY * (b2);

            b1 = oneMinusX * grey + fractionX * grey;
            b2 = oneMinusX * grey + fractionX *grey;
            red = oneMinusY * (b1)+fractionY * (b2);

            oRow[x + x + x] = blue;
            oRow[x + x + x + 1] = green;
            oRow[x + x + x + 2] = red;
       }
```

I've tried unrolling it by changing the loop counter to

```
for (UINT x = 0; x < 2000; x+=2)
```

and adding 2000 to x before repeating the code, but it's not working well

Comment: Have you checked if your compiler does any unrolling for you? I mean, when you enable optimizations, and checked by looking at the generated assembly (when you ask your compiler to write it to file).

Comment: By "not working well" I mean it's only changing the first half of the image to greyscale. Sorry I wasn't specific in the question

Comment: Another hint, which might or might not help the compiler optimize for you: define variables in the narrowest scope possible, so inside the loop if you only need them inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

> I've tried unrolling it by changing the loop counter to
>
> `for (UINT x = 0; x < 2000; x+=2)`
>
> and adding 2000 to x before repeating the code, but it's not working well

The logic for your loop unrolling is flawed. You need to process elements at `x` and `x + 1` on each iteration, not `x` and `x + 2000`, and the upper limit would still be 4000:

```
for (UINT x = 0; x < 4000; x+=2)
{
    // do stuff for element x
    // ...

    // do stuff for element x + 1
    // ...
}
```

As has already been noted though, you may be wasting your time. Compilers are pretty good at unrolling code when needed, and manual loop unrolling can even be counter-productive on modern CPUs.

Pro tips: make sure you're compiling with all optimisations enabled (e.g. `gcc -O3 ...` ), and profile your code to make sure that this loop really does need optimising. If you do decide that you need to optimise this code then there are some very obvious inefficiencies that you could work on before resorting to loop unrolling.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UINT x = 0; x < 2000; x+=2)
```

Will loop 1000 values: 0, 2, 4 ... 1998

This is probably not what you want. Either you want

```
for (UINT x = 0; x < 2000; x+=1) // values 0, 1, ... 1999
```

or

```
for (UINT x = 0; x < 4000; x+=2) // values 0, 2, ... 3998
```

Comment: If I change it to :
for (UINT x = 0; x < 2000; x++) without unrolling any code
half of the image becomes grey,

but if I then add x += 2000; and repeat the code, none of the image turns grey